# Totem fails at start (totem:3808), after activating dbus plugin

Tags: totem, zeitgeist, dbus, segmentation-fault, glib

I am using Ubuntu 11.10; Kernel: Linux 3.0.0-14-generic with Gnome 3.2.1

Yesterday I was browsing through the totem plugins and accidentally hit activate on the dbus plugin.
When I started Totem after that, it showed the UI for like a second and then quit.
I ran it in terminal and got the following error output:

```
(totem:3808): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: Property 'object' on class
'ZeitgeistDpPlugin' has type 'TotemObject' which is different from the type 
'GObject', of the property on interface 'PeasActivatable'

Segmentation fault
```

I don't really get what it's trying to tell me...though I am pretty sure that I messed up something by turning on that plugin.

So I would like to know how to deactivate it again...outside of totem. I would also like to know what actually caused the failure.

Comment: I moved the answer out of your question and into a real "Answer". In the future, feel free to post answers to your own questions to help future visitors find the solutions as quickly as possible.

Comment: thanks, I actually wanted to do that but it told me that I couldn't answer my own questions

Comment: yeah, I think you might have to wait a couple days after posting the question before you can answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be fixed by deleting the `dbus` folder in the `/usr/lib/totem/plugins` directory.

If there is another more elegant way to do this please comment...